# round function not working in PostgresSql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to just compute a simple round() function.

e.g.

```
SELECT ROUND(quantity, 2) 
FROM farmers_market.customer_purchases;
```

However, instead of getting a rounded value for quantity I get the following error

SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: function round(real, integer) does not exist

Everything I look up says that simple code should work. But no matter what it just gives me back that error.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: The error is saying that there is no version of the function `ROUND()` that works with those parameter types. I think, and I'm no expert here, that `ROUND()` doesn't take in a `real` type as the first parameter. You may have to cast: `ROUND(quantity::numeric, 2)`

Comment: Yes look at the docs [Math functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-math.html) for the two forms of `round()`.

Comment: @JNevill thanks, that seems to have worked. But what's the logic behind it, if my column already only contains numeric data within it, why do I have to specify ::numeric?

It doesn't help that the training course I'm reading from is using MySQL instead.